# The class name that Rails generate controller generate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

For some reason I can't run a `rails generate controller` on my machine at the moment, something is messed up but still I need a controller. So decided to create it by hand.

But I can't remember the conventions: when I was saying `rails generate controller Therapeutics` was it creating a

```
therapeutics_controller.rb
```

and a

```
therapeutics.html.haml
```

So I can create them by hand?

And what was the class name in the controller? Would it be `class TherpeuticsController` ?

Comment: I think I would look into why I couldn't run the controller first, but yes you can do it by hand.  Everything looks right except the html file should be index.html.haml in a folder under views called therapeutic.

Comment: Yes, `class TherpeuticsController < ApplicationController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

app/controllers/therapeutics_controller.rb should be

```
class TherapeuticsController < ApplicationController

  # define your actions here..

end
```

app/views/therapeutics => put in your views here

and that's it. if you need helper or model, simply create it by hand. the rails generators are very convenient, but understanding the conventions and creating it by your own gives you more flexibility.

for better understanding, simple check out the basics http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 1):

Just ran it and this is what I got:

```
$new_project  rails generate controller Therapeutics
      create  app/controllers/therapeutics_controller.rb
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/therapeutics
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/therapeutics_helper.rb
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/therapeutics.js.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/therapeutics.css.scss
$new_project
```